# pyqtgraph documentation example doesn't work with PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I'm starting to use pyqtgraph.  I tried running the example code below, but it gives an error.  This example code came from [this page](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/qtcrashcourse.html#graphicsview-and-graphicsitems) in the documentation.  The only change I made was to import QtGui from PySide instead of PyQt4, which the comments explicitly say should work.

**The Question**
How can I fix this error?  Am I using the wrong version of something? Is this a bug in PySide?

*Note*: I know that I can use PyQt4 instead of PySide, but that is not a valid workaround for me, for several reasons (both licensing and a desire to get on the PySide bandwagon).

**What I know about the error**

- The example works perfectly if I import QtGui from PyQt4
- The complaint seems to be that I'm trying to add a PlotWidget to a QGridLayout, using its addWidget method, but only QWidget objects are allowed.  This makes no sense, because AFAIK PlotWidget is a descendant of QWidget.  I'm guessing this is a problem with wrapping of the underlying Qt library?
- Using:

  - Ubuntu 14.04
  - PySide 1.2.1
  - `PySide.QtCore.qVersion` gives '4.8.6'
  - `PySide.QtCore.__version__` is also '4.8.6', meaning PySide was compiled with the same Qt version I am using.

**The Error to be fixed**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<some file I made>", line 133, in <module>
    testPlot0()
  File "<some file I made>", line 52, in testPlot0
    layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1)  # plot goes on right side, spanning 3 rows
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PlotWidget, int, int, int, int)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget, int, int, PySide.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = 0)
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget, int, int, int, int, PySide.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = 0)
  PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget)
```

**The Code that produced this error**

```
from PySide import QtGui  # (the example applies equally well to PySide)
import pyqtgraph as pg

## Always start by initializing Qt (only once per application)
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Define a top-level widget to hold everything
w = QtGui.QWidget()

## Create some widgets to be placed inside
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('press me')
text = QtGui.QLineEdit('enter text')
listw = QtGui.QListWidget()
plot = pg.PlotWidget()

## Create a grid layout to manage the widgets size and position
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)

## Add widgets to the layout in their proper positions
layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 0)   # button goes in upper-left
layout.addWidget(text, 1, 0)   # text edit goes in middle-left
layout.addWidget(listw, 2, 0)  # list widget goes in bottom-left
layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1)  # plot goes on right side, spanning 3 rows

## Display the widget as a new window
w.show()

## Start the Qt event loop
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with PySide v1.2.2 and pyqtgraph 0.9.10 on Windows. Could be a bug in PySide v1.2.1? I know you have your reasons for using PySide but I've found it to be annoyingly buggy, and no one seems to be maintaining the project much any more.

Comment: I am beginning to see what you mean, although [it seems](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/pyside/2015-July/002313.html) that we do still have some maintenance going on recently.

Comment: Okay, now the problematic code works great for me.  I'm thoroughly confused.  I did upgrade from ubuntu 14.04.02 to 14.04.03 before coming back to this problem.  Maybe that had something to do with it... Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably going on, is that pyqtgraph doesn't use an agnostic import, but is using the specific PyQt imports and is creating the type widget:

`PyQt.QtGui.QWidget`

instead of

`PySide.QtGui.QWidget`

You probably need to go into the source of pyqtgraph and change its imports to match yours.

### Supporting Both PySide and PyQt at the same time

At the bottom of this page:

https://wiki.qt.io/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt

it talks about how to make your code more agnostic to pyside v pyqt imports... either using `py_compat.py` or building/installing a middleware loader called `python_qt_binding`, and then changing all of your headers to use the neutral one.

Comment: Sounds promising.  I'll give it a try and post results.

Comment: Pyqtgraph does do agnostic imports. I think the problem is somewhere else (unless the import code has developed a bug since I last used it...)

Comment: looking at that page, I think I agree with three_pinapples: I don't think this is the problem.  Also, the code snippet in question has mysteriously started working after doing an upgrade of my ubuntu.  The problem has got to be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and stumbled accros [this link](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#pyqt-and-pyside).

Apparently you need to

> If you have both libraries installed on your system and you wish to force pyqtgraph to use one or the other, simply make sure it is imported before pyqtgraph:

like so:

```
import PySide  ## this will force pyqtgraph to use PySide instead of PyQt4
import pyqtgraph as pg
```

This solved my issue.